# sharing a namespace across multiple ipython notebooks

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to work with several ipython notebooks at once sharing the same namespace. Is there currently (ipython-1.1.0) a way to do this?

I tried creating different notebooks on the same ipython kernel, but the notebooks don't share a namespace. Also, I've been able to use a terminal console alongside a notebook on the same namespace using the answers in [Using IPython console along side IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479645/using-ipython-console-along-side-ipython-notebook), but I couldn't find the notebook equivalent of the --existing argument.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this no longer works, you get error message ipython.kernel replaced by ipython.parallel.

A less elegant way than above to alter this is to change IPython/frontend/html/notebook/kernelmanager.py around line 273 from

kernel_id = self.kernel_for_notebook(notebook_id)

to

```
kernel_id = None
for notebook_id in self._notebook_mapping:
    kernel_id = self._notebook_mapping[notebook_id]
    break
```

For Anaconda python, replace start_kernel in kernelmanager.py with

```
def start_kernel(self, kernel_id=None, path=None, **kwargs):
    global saved_kernel_id
    if saved_kernel_id:
        return saved_kernel_id
    if kernel_id is None:
        kwargs['extra_arguments'] = self.kernel_argv
        if path is not None:
            kwargs['cwd'] = self.cwd_for_path(path)
        kernel_id = super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
        self.log.info("Kernel started: %s" % kernel_id)
        self.log.debug("Kernel args: %r" % kwargs)
        self.add_restart_callback(kernel_id,
            lambda : self._handle_kernel_died(kernel_id),
            'dead',
        )
    else:
        self._check_kernel_id(kernel_id)
        self.log.info("Using existing kernel: %s" % kernel_id)
    saved_kernel_id = kernel_id
    return kernel_id
```

and add

```
    saved_kernel_id = None
```

above

```
    class MappingKernelManager(MultiKernelManager):
```

True IPython gurus, please supply the correct fix. A lot of people using notebooks want the ability to share the kernel, it's natural, because one notebook quickly grows too big to work with a single complex application, so it is easier to be able to break down the application into multiple notebooks.

Also, gurus, while you're listening, it would be nice to have a collapse-expand feature as in Mathematica so you can only view the part of the notebook you care about and you can zoom out the rest.

Answer (score 4):

The IPython Notebook does not have the equivalent of `--existing`. Notebooks do not share kernels. It is not a limitation of the notebook itself, it is just a design decision made in the notebook server code. The server code can be modified, for instance, to have all notebooks share the same kernel. You can do this with a little monkeypatching in your IPython configuration. Start by creating a profile:

```
$ ipython profile create singlekernel
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'~/.ipython/profile_singlekernel/ipython_config.py'
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'~/.ipython/profile_singlekernel/ipython_qtconsole_config.py'
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'~/.ipython/profile_singlekernel/ipython_notebook_config.py'
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'~/.ipython/profile_singlekernel/ipython_nbconvert_config.py'
```

and edit `$(ipython locate profile singlekernel)/ipython_notebook_config.py` to contain:

```
# Configuration file for ipython-notebook.

c = get_config()

import os
import uuid
from IPython.kernel.multikernelmanager import MultiKernelManager

def start_kernel(self, **kwargs):
    """Minimal override of MKM.start_kernel that always returns the same kernel"""
    kernel_id = kwargs.pop('kernel_id', str(uuid.uuid4()))
    if self.km is None:
        self.km = self.kernel_manager_factory(connection_file=os.path.join(
                self.connection_dir, "kernel-%s.json" % kernel_id),
                parent=self, autorestart=True, log=self.log
    )
    if not self.km.is_alive():
        self.log.info("starting single kernel")
        self.km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
    else:
        self.log.info("reusing existing kernel")
    self._kernels[kernel_id] = self.km
    return kernel_id

MultiKernelManager.km = None
MultiKernelManager.start_kernel = start_kernel
```

This just overrides the kernel starting mechanism to start only one kernel and return it at every subsequent request,
rather than starting a new one for each kernel ID.

Now whenever you start the notebook server with

```
ipython notebook --profile singlekernel
```

all of the notebooks in that session will share the same kernel.

Comment: This would be perfect for me, but unfortunately doesn't work (for me at least) in 2021. Anyone an idea what to adjust to make it work again? (I'm specifically using: jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.3.0
qtconsole        : 5.0.3
ipython          : 7.22.0
ipykernel        : 5.5.3
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.0.16
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.1.3
traitlets        : 5.0.5
)