# When an ipython console connect to an existing kernel linked to a notebook, %load magic can not load code into console

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I learned this trick from [Using IPython console along side IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479645/using-ipython-console-along-side-ipython-notebook) . But when I connect this kernel using console, the %load magic will load file into a pager (like you you do 'man thecodefile.py' in console), not to the input line.

Anyone know how to change these behavior back to default?

Answer (score 0):

You ask two question here, please ask them separately.
As for `!su ausername` there is no way to forward stdin through subprocess.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can just workaround this by making two steps, first go 'sh' then do 'su username' there. I will remove that part from the question.